# Set Synaptics "three finger press" to an action?

Tags: windows-8, synaptics-touchpad

In the settings panel for certain Synaptics clickpad/touchpads is an option for executing a "program" on three-finger-presses. I'm hoping there's an easy way to have a three-finger-press excute an action, like emitting key presses.
I tried setting a vb-script, but it doesn't always activate the script. The script I tried:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.SendKeys "^w"
MsgBox("Hello world")
```

With this set, it *sometimes* presents the "hello world" message box. It never seems to emit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>, which is my goal.

Comment: What operating system do you use? Some Windows flavor I imagine since you mentioned vb-script.

Comment: That is Correct.

Comment: Yes, please include _which_ version of Windows you are using. The answer could depend on it.

Comment: I mainly use Windows 8.